# Allow only one thread to get result

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

I am a bit new in paralell programming and trying to find a solution for a next problem:
Lets have a simple function:

```
private void doRefreshData()
{
  items = getUpdatedData();
}
```

getUpdatedData() is a really time comsumpting function and return dictionary.
Problem is, that function doRefreshData() may and will be called from multiple threads at once. I would like to achieve, that only first thread will run function, others just wait for the result. Simple lock() is not good, because other threads will also run getUpdatedData(), even if it is not necessary - they have a work already done by other thread.

So I need something like:

```
private void doRefreshData()
{
  if (isAlreadyRunning) {
    waitForResult();
    return;
  }
}

  items = getUpdatedData();
}
```

I know, there is a workaround, but I am sure, that there is already a solution for this problem (Mutex?,Auto/ManualResetEvent?, SomethingElseWithFancyName?)

Update: After the first thread finished work and others also left, it is necessary to allow new thread to run this function - it is OK to ask for a new, refreshed data, even a few seconds later.

Comment: If already running why do you need to wait simply returning isn't enough?

Comment: Because other threads need to work with new, refreshed data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could consider using a variant of the code that the `lock` statement actually generates by using `Monitor.TryEnter()` instead of `Monitor.Enter`:

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(_myLock))
{
    try
    {
        // Your code
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_myLock);
    }
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Then if the lock has already been obtained by an other thread, you can do something else instead.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a working and simpliest aproach, still testing:  `            if (Monitor.TryEnter(locker))
            {
                items = RefreshData();
                Monitor.Exit(locker);
            }
            else
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }`

Comment: @HoGo I wouldn't do `lock(locker) { return; }` there, as otherwise you're just blocking the thread until the other thread releases the lock, making the use of `Monitor.TryEnter()` a bit redundant.

Comment: I know, but this is what I want to achieve, other threads has to wait for a result. Otherway they will exit quickly and will have no data. `code`

Answer (score 5):

You can easily implement the required logic using tasks and `async`/`await`.

The `doRefreshData` method should return a `Task<TResult>` of the appropriate type. Here's a dummy method that does nothing for two seconds and then returns a "result":

```
async Task<object> RealGetData()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return 42;
}
```

Since you want multiple methods to request the data concurrently and have their requests satisfied with the same result, you need to somehow remember that there is a "get data" operation already underway. You also need some kind of thread synchronization to eliminate race conditions, so:

```
private Task<object> currentCalculation;
private object lockTarget = new object(); // just for lock()
```

Now it's trivial to write an `async` method that either starts a new calculation if none is pending, or else hooks you up to receive the result of the pending one:

```
async Task<object> GetData()
{
    lock (lockTarget)
    {
        if (currentCalculation != null && !currentCalculation.IsCompleted)
        {
            return currentCalculation;
        }

        return currentCalculation = Task.Run<object>(RealGetData);
    }
}
```

Using this is super easy: any time you want access to "fresh" data, write `await GetData()` and you will always get a new result back; the code will automatically queue you up to get the result being currently calculated or start a new calculation for you. For example, this will start off a single calculation and satisfy all 10 requests with its result:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Console.WriteLine(await GetData());
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but the only problem is, that this caching mechanism I would like to create is an abstract class - to be able to use it with more data collections from database. And in this case `public abstract async Task<T> RealRefreshData();` gives me _The 'async' modifier can only be used in methods that have a statement body_ error

Comment: @HoGo: You can simply remove the `async` modifier from `RealRefreshData`, it's an implementation detail that I happened to use in *this* implementation. Not "required".

Answer (score 3):

If it only needed to fire once, I'd suggest using [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As it is, I'd use [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and some [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) calls. Something like:

```
private Task<DataValue> _pendingRefresh;

private void doRefreshData()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<DataValue>();
    //See if there's one in flight
    var task = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _pendingRefresh, tcs.Task, null);
    if (task != null)
    {
        task.Wait(); //Or async, etc
        var items = task.Result;
    }
    else
    {
      try{
        var items = getUpdatedData();
        tcs.SetResult(items); //?
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          tcs.SetException(ex);
          throw;
      } finally {
        //Allow a new call to run 
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _pendingRefresh, null); 
      }
    }
}
```

Basically, only one caller will ever be able to change `_pendingRefresh` from being `null` to not `null`. It will then do the work, and signal the `Task` once the work is complete. Other callers go into the top half of the `if` and wait for the `Task` to be marked as complete.

Once the "caller that was allowed to do the work" has finished and signalled the task, it sets `_pendingRefresh` back to `null`. To allow a new caller to do the work and make a new call.

---

Note, I've also added some better error handling so that hopefully, if `getUpdatedData` throws an exception, you don't end up with lots of callers stuck waiting for a task to complete that never will. They'll get errors, but at least you'll know about it on all affected threads.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use a named Mutex here. The reason to go for named here is so that it is easier to set a shared synchronisation point. Not naming a mutex only works when you share the mutex across threads. You could do that here, but I found that naming them is easier.

```
// Create a new named mutex and try to obtain a lock on it immediately.
// The WaitOne operation below ensures that you will have to wait when
// another thread has the lock.
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true,"SynchronisationPoint");

// Wait for the mutex to become available.
// If you get beyond this point it means that you are the only 
// one performing this operation.
mutex.WaitOne();

// Check if the operation was already completed.
// When it was, do nothing here.
if(isCompleted) {
  return;
}

// Perform the operation.
items = getUpdatedData();
```

Comment: OP wants other threads to not run getUpdatedData after one thread has acquired the lock.

Comment: A named mutex is a machine-wide lock. Just FYI. It's not for convenience.